# Find specific file types located within each user's %AppData% directory using powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to accomplish the following using a powershell script:

- Find all json files located within each user's `%AppData%` directory.
- Output to the console in the following format: `.json found in`

I'm new to PowerShell and have the following so far,

```
$AppData = Get-ChildItem $env:SystemDrive\Users | where {$_.PsIsContainer} | Foreach-Object {$_.FullName}
$Result=Get-ChildItem -Filter *.json -recurse

ForEach ($result in $appdata) { IF($Result -like '*.json') {$result }}
```

I need to figure out how to append the folder name of appdata to the `$AppData` variable output.

Is there a better way then using a ForEach loop?

Comment: `Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\*\AppData' -Filter '*.json' -Recurse`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using `ForEach-Object` cmdlet for enumerate elements and then using `Write-Host` cmdlet display results in console. Like so:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\TMP -Filter '*.json' -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $('{0} found in {1}' -f $_.Name, ([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($_.FullName)))
}
```